# Upload large mapping into smart contract

Tags: solidity

Lets say you have very large array file in the following format:

```
[{
   "address": "0x123",
   "state": true
},
{
   "address: "0x234",
   "state": false
}]
```

Implement a function that would allow you to record this data into smart contract.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? What issues did you run into?

Comment: so far here is what I have done: https://github.com/rstormsf/ico_per_week/blob/002_whitelisted/contracts/BlockchainLabsCrowdsale.sol using an array as argument, and assign to `mapping` cause I can't use mappings in args nor structs that have mappings inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that by "very large" you mean that it will be too big to fit all the uploads into a single transaction (or block).

The first approach that you linked in your comments doesn't seem to actually need a mapping (the array method seems to work).

```
function whitelistAddresses(address[] _addresses) onlyOwner {
    require(!whitelistInitialized);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) {
        addresses[_addresses[i]] = true;
    }
    whitelistInitialized = true;
}
```

Let's assume you have other reasons to want a struct/mapping, like an expiration date field. You could approach it in roughly the same way:

```
mapping (address => uint) public expirations;

function whitelistAddresses(address[] _addresses, uint[] expirations) onlyOwner {
    require(!whitelistInitialized);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) {
        addresses[_addresses[i]] = expirations[i];
    }
    whitelistInitialized = true;
}
```

But you have too much to fit in one block, so you could split the array into chunks, call whitelist repeatedly, and then lock it down:

```
mapping (address => uint) public expirations;

function whitelistAddresses(address[] _addresses, uint[] expirations) onlyOwner {
    require(!whitelistInitialized);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) {
        addresses[_addresses[i]] = expirations[i];
    }
}

function whitelistLockdown() onlyOwner {
    whitelistInitialized = true;
}
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't think about that. Thank you very much for your answer